# Loading Original Values of Collection EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using current Version of EF core and got trouble to load the original values.

I've the following constellation:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class UserRole
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Now I add a new UserRole to the User - something like that

```
user.UserRoles.Add(new UserRole() {Name="Admin", User=user}
```

After that I want to "revert" this step and tried to use Reload

```
dbContext.Entry(user).Reload();
```

But still there is the new Role added to the Collection.
I also tried

```
dbContext.Entry(user).Collection(x=>x.UserRole).Load();
```

But this also not work.

Is there something I am doing generally wrong?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: To revert adding to collection - remove item from collection. Other hacks with ChangeTracker can be problematic.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv but isnt it very uncomfortable if I need to do that for multiple values. Lets say someone want to configure Roles to the user and want to reverse this action right after. In this case I need another List with to "old" values to rollback. Whats your suggestion for that?

Comment: So, then create new DbContext and reload entities again.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the context? `dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().ForEach(e => e.State = EntityState.Detached);` or [ChangeTracker.Clear()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.changetracker.clear?view=efcore-5.0) if you are using EF Core 5.0.

Comment: Thank you for you response. ChangeTracker.Clear() did the trick!

Comment: You're welcome. I'll create an answer now.

Comment: Note `.Clear()` will revert all unsaved changes.

Comment: Good point @AluanHaddad. I forgot to mention that. I've added that info to the answer.

Comment: in my case the revert was no problem! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can reset the context using
`dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()ToList().ForEach(e => e.State = EntityState.Detached);`. If you are using EF Core 5.0, you can use [ChangeTracker.Clear()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.changetracker.clear?view=efcore-5.0).

Note: As @AluanHaddad says in one of the comments on the question, this will revert all unsaved changes. You can use a linq `Where` expression to limit which objects have their states reset:

```
dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()
.Where(e => e.Entity is UserRole)
.Where(e => e => e.State = EntityState.Added)
.ToList()
.ForEach(e => e.State = EntityState.Detached);
```

Also, you could consider implementing the [Unit of work pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) so that there is less risk of having unrelated changes a that will be reverted.

Comment: well I use IDbContextFactory so the scope have to be really short anyway. Otherwise I risk concurrency problems inside my blazor-app